# Program Flow using Events

Tags: c#

I'm trying to write a program where  Step 1 -> Kick off Step 2 -> kick off step 3. Variables are passed in between each step.

Can I use events this way in C#? What might be the best way to write a program that does this?

```
public class ProgramFlow // the listener program
{
    EventArgs args = null;
    public delegate void EventHandler(string str, EventArgs e);
    public static event EventHandler Step1Reached;
    public static event EventHandler Step2Reached;        
    public ProgramFlow()
    {
        Step1 step1 = new Step1();  
        // Print string and kick off Step2 
        Step2 step2 =new Step2();
        // Print String kick off next step 
    }
}

public class Step1
{
    string charRead;

    public Step1()
    {
        Console.Write("Input something for Step1: ");
        charRead = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine();            
        ProgramFlow.Step1Reached += ProgramFlow_Step1Reached;
    }

    void ProgramFlow_Step2Reached(string str, EventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(charRead);
    }

}

public class Step2
{
    string charRead;
    public Step2()
    {
        Console.Write("Input something for Step2: ");
        charRead = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine();
        ProgramFlow.Step2Reached += ProgramFlow_Step2Reached;
    }

    void ProgramFlow_Step2Reached(string str, EventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(charRead);
    }
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ProgramFlow programFlow = new ProgramFlow();
        Console.ReadKey();              
    }
}
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1):

Would interfacing the steps out and having your program flow coordinate their execution meet your requirements e.g.

```
public class ProgramFlow // the listener program
{
    public ProgramFlow()
    {
        IStep[] steps = new IStep[] { new Step1(), new Step2() };

        foreach (var step in steps)
        {
            step.Step();
            step.StepResult();
        }
    }
}

public interface IStep
{
    void Step();
    void StepResult();
}

public class Step1 : IStep
{
    string stringRead;

    public void Step()
    {
        Console.Write("Input something for Step1: ");
        stringRead = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine();
    }

    public void StepResult()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(stringRead);
    }
}

public class Step2 : IStep
{
    string stringRead;

    public void Step()
    {
        Console.Write("Input something for Step2: ");
        stringRead = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine();
    }

    public void StepResult()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(stringRead);
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ProgramFlow programFlow = new ProgramFlow();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: Close but not really. I'm going to be waiting for other events in step1 for example I'm waiting for serial data.  I'm looking at this example. I want to do something similar but with more steps. http://dotnet.dzone.com/articles/introduction-event-driven

Answer (score 0):

Events will help you out when you want extensibility provided without deriving new objects and are very useful when you want more than one action to occur.  Events can help when you are using out of order execution (although async could help you there too).  If you have any out of order, or if you want to report progress back to a GUI then yes, events are a great way to achieve that.

To be honest, if you need action 1, action 2 and action 3 to occur in that order, wouldn't the code be simpler and more maintainable if you simply wrote:

```
public static void Main()
{
     var arg1 = ReadAction1();
     Action1(arg1);
     var arg2 = ReadAction2();
     Action2(arg2);
     var arg3 = ReadAction3();
     Action3(arg3);
}
```

That said, this is taking you down a very imperative path.  I'd be looking to see if you can represent your task in an OO way so that you can get something you can swap out and test etc.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm looking for something more event driven. I'm reading serial data from a scanner and then printing bar codes and then reading them back in. I don't think it would be possible to do it your way.

Comment: in that case, you would benefit from representing the scanner as an object.  You would wrap a polling loop around the serial port to see barcodes and when you get one, throw an event "Barcode Received"

Comment: that event can be subscribed to by your code to then launch the actions.